# tar a complete, stand-alone python installation on ubuntu

Tags: python, bash

I'm working on a bash script to create a tar file of a complete python installation (including the executable).

The idea is to untar the installation into a home directory on a remote machine, rather than `configure/make`'ing it. I should be able to untar the archive on the remote machine, change the `PATH` and be able to call that python installation on the remove machine. It is to save bootstrap time on EMR.

How do I tar a complete, stand-alone python installation on ubuntu?

### EDIT:

I've requested Bioconductor's AMI in the jobflow, bypassing software install issues at bootstrap time. Also, when hitting the bootstrap time limit, simply use a larger instance size. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tar a directory, you use `tar -cf output_file.tar /path/to/installation` - since it's a stand-alone installation, everything should be contained in the installation directory.

However, this is a bad idea. The reason Python (and pretty much every other package) is distributed with a configure script is, machines, architectures and installed dependencies differ. Running `configure` on the destination machine is the only way to ensure that the produced binaries will run without problems on it.

The only case where you'd be able to copy the already installed package is when you are sure that you'll be running on the same architecture, the same distribution, the same version, and the same list of already installed packages as the machine you copied it from.

Comment: AWS support advised to tar software rather than run config & make since there is a time limit on bootstrapping slave nodes. Distributing tar archives across slave nodes is easily done (cache.archives). I'm stumbling on getting the python installation properly tarred. I've added the `whereis python2.7` files to the tarball, but still can't get it to run. I was hoping someone had written a bash script to do something similar with python.

Comment: Can you detail what "can't get it to run" means?

Comment: The EMR job flow fails with Steps → Jobs → Tasks → Task Attempts:
`The specified domain does not exist`. When I check the stderr in the nodes, I see `dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: `. I do run my bootstrap bash script locally prior to copying it on S3, and it works fine.

Comment: That doesn't look like a `tar` problem. Try adding `echo foo >&2` lines to your script to find out where exactly it fails.